# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico (“default-src”)

Tags: express, content-security-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

I keep having this error when I try opening another of my apps's routes:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico (“default-src”).
```

I read other questions with the same error but changing my meta tag hasn't gotten rid of the issue. This is how it looks like now:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; child-src 'none';" />
```

I'm also the same error on Firefox, Chrome, and Brave. This is the full error I'm getting on Firefox 107.0:

[image: Firefox 107]

Edit: I removed my meta tag and changed it to set my CORS from the server but I don't know how to define CSP from Express.

Here's what I added on the server:

```
const cors = require('cors')
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

I'm still getting the CSP error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you can see the response header "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'". This blocks all pretty much all sources from loading on that page. Note that content needs to pass all policies, so adding another one won't make any difference in this case. You need to figure out where the "default-src 'none'" header is set and modify or remove it.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to set it now from the server because it seems like the more secure way but I'm not sure how you define CSP inside the Express CORS package (code at the bottom of my edited answer)